# 777 small wing panel moving all the time during landing

Tags: aircraft-design, landing, boeing-777, control-surfaces

What is the small wing panel called that moves up and down all the time during landing?

See the following video:

What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @Pondlife - The posting "How does the particular piece of flap behind an engine on a B777 work?" does not clearly show which flap it is referring to like the photo here.  The same posting also says the flaperon is a high-speed aileron - why did it continue to move when the plane slowed down to landing speed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: flaperon]

That control surface is called a [flaperon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaperon).

The flaperon functions as both a [flap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flap_(aeronautics)) and an [aileron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aileron) to provide roll control, as with an aileron, and increased lift and drag, as with flaps. The flaperons on either wing move down together as flaps, and move up and down opposite each other as ailerons.

In the video, steady movement following that of the surrounding flaps from one position to another is an indication of operation in the role of a flap. If we could see the other wing we would see that flaperon moving in sequence. However, the short up and down movements, as opposed to the stationary flaps, is an indication of operation in the role of an aileron. If we could see the other wing we would see that flaperon moving opposite the flaperon in the video.